# When trying to blit a background in pygame, I get this error message

Tags: python, pygame, blit

I'm new to pygame as of yesterday, and I keep running into this issue when trying to blit anything onto the screen. I am running mac osx 10.6.8. I am writing it all out in textwrangler, and executing it in the terminal with `python2.7-32 filename.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "adventure.py", line 35, in <module>
    screen.blit(background(0, 0))
TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable
```

Here is [my python program](http://pastebin.com/CJ6yJWFC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `screen.blit(background(0, 0))` to `screen.blit(background,(0, 0))` (without the comma, you are treating `background` as a function/callable instead of as a parameter. Think of it like calling a function named `background` with the argument `(0, 0)`.). `screen.blit`'s two required arguments are a `source` and a `destination`, so putting a comma after `background` supplies both arguments (`source` is `background`, `destination` is `(0, 0)`).

Comment: Ah yes! Thank you very much for explaining that! Source and destination. So you can pretty much `screen.blit(pygame.image.load('bg.bmp'),(0, 0))` without creating a variable to load the image first? Thank you sir!

Comment: @Matthias From what I can tell, you got it :) Good luck with everything! If this answer was what you were looking for, you can click on the little check mark under the answer score to 'accept' it - this indicates that your question was answered and will effectively close the loop (however if it isn't what you were looking for, free free to leave unchecked, of course :) ).